AWS ECS Cluster failed to create a service: ECSService CREATE_FAILED
I use AWS on the free tier plan.
I'm trying to deploy a docker container to AWS ECS Fargate and I have succeeded in creating the cluster, and the task definition but I have an issue with the creation of the service for the cluster. Every time I try to create a service it fails and the error message of the last one was:
ECSService   CREATE_FAILED
with the reason:
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." (RequestToken: 5d9d7d5f-0bf0-2630-d037-40acc639f272, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

How to solve this issue? What is happening?

All that error is telling you is that it tried to start your ECS task several times, but it failed. You need to leave the CloudFormation dashboard and go into the ECS dashboard to look at the failed task to see what the actual error message is. You also need to go into CloudWatch Logs and look at the logs for the ECS task to see if errors occurred inside the container. Until you get to those actual error messages there is no way for anyone to help you, because it will all just be a total guess as to what is wrong.
